# Maximum usage of CPU with a query

Tags: python, optimization, cpu-usage

I'm trying to perform this search for the smallest entity. the list "Titles" have around 5Mio. items and it's a list. Every title will be placed against the entity.

My question is, how can I optimize this search? It is possible for me to maximize the use of CPU by using this search in parallel?

Any tips or any research guides are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

```py
    for we in titles:
        dist = stringdist.levenshtein_norm(we, ent)

        if dist < best_1:
            best_1 = dist
            best_match_1 = we

        elif dist < best_2:
            best_2 = dist
            best_match_2 = we
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is using the python `multiprocessing` module. Turn this into a map-reduce problem using a worker pool to run `stringdist.levenshtein_norm` over everything in `titles`, and have each function return `(dist,ent)` as a tuple. Then take `min()`, which will give you both the minimum score and the entry.

If you are running on a system with 96 cores, you'll see ≈96x speedup.

If you are running on a system with 1 core, you won't see a speedup.

You can also make this faster by rewriting `stringdist.levenshtein_norm` to run on a GPU, or in machine code.

Comment: Working with NumPy array instead of a list could help?

Comment: NumPy array won't help, because NumPy won't parallelize `stringdist.levenshtein_norm`.